# How do I make Datagridview row based?

Tags: winforms

Here is an example image of a datagridview.

I'd like to make this row based so instead of a cell being selected I'd like the entire row to be selected. The rows/cells are read only so no cell needs to be edited. also I like to remove the leftmost side where the > is.

(Crappy image found via google)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myGrid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
myGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

You can set these properties in code as above, or via the designer.  `RowHeadersVisible` is under the `Appearance` section. `SelectionMode` is under the `Behavior` section.

Answer (score 0):

For the full row select part of the question, the DataGridView control has a property called SelectionMode. Set that property to SelectionMode.FullRowSelect.

Not sure if the leftmost part can be removed but you can changed the width of it to 1 or 2 pixels. Cannot remember what it is called but there is a property on the DataGrifView control that controls the width of that first 'row indicator' column.